# Node pipe stops working

Tags: node.js, post

My client sends an image file to the server. It works 5 times and then it suddenly stops. I am pretty new using streams and pipe so I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Server Code

```
http.createServer(function(req, res) {

  console.log("File received");
  // This opens up the writeable stream to `output`
  var name = "./test"+i+".jpg";
  var writeStream = fs.createWriteStream(name);

  // This pipes the POST data to the file
  req.pipe(writeStream);

  req.on('end', function () {
  console.log("File saved");
  i++;
});

// This is here incase any errors occur
writeStream.on('error', function (err) {
   console.log(err);
 });
}).listen(3000);
```

Client code

```
var request = require('request');
var fs = require('fs');

setInterval(function () {
    var readStream  = fs.createReadStream('./test.jpg');
    readStream.on('open', function () {
    // This just pipes the read stream to the response object (which goes to the client)
    readStream.pipe(request.post('http://192.168.1.100:3000/test'));
    console.log("Send file to server");

  });


}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to do the following on the server side to make this work :

```
res.statusCode = 200;
res.end();
```

Answer (score 0):

Behaves like a resource exhaustion issue.  Not sure which calls throw errors and which just return.  Does the server connect on the 6th call?  Does the write stream open?  Does the pipe open?

Try ending the connection and closing the pipe after the image is saved.  Maybe close the write stream too, don't remember if node garbage collects file descriptors.

Comment: Thanks for the response , I found out what I did wrong. In my server code I had to call res.statusCode = 200; and res.end();